# Wine gives error: "Failed to import system certs into registry, 00000057"

Tags: drivers, wine

I have been trying to use WINE to run a Windows driver for a digital audio interface in Linux.  However, running:

```
wine saffire-mixcontrol-3.4.exe
```

yields this result:

```
002c:err:winediag:load_gssapi_krb5 Failed to load libgssapi_krb5, Kerberos SSP support will not be available.
002c:err:crypt:CRYPT_ImportSystemRootCertsToReg Failed to import system certs into registry, 00000057
```

It also presents a WINE dialog with this warning:

```
Runtime error (at 15:863):

Access violation at address 7DF1B5D3.  Read of address 00000008.
```

Any suggestions as to what I might try?

(Note: My OS is MX Linux 19.4 Patito Feo 64-bit.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but there is no way you can install a windows driver on linux using wine. Also, I don't see this driver available on linux. None of the focusrite products have drivers for linux, only windows and mac.